# How to add parameters to the url in all links to the page

Tags: razor, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET CORE MVC application, and I want to add the same parameter to all the links on my page.

E.g. Add the  `companyId` parameter to all links:

```
http:\\site.com\admin?companyId=3
```

I would like to open the first page in the controller with the parameter `companyId`, and have this parameter stored and added to all the links on the page leading to this controller.

Comment: I try create TagHelper for `<a></a>` but `companyId` lost when I send form

Comment: If what you are saying is that you want to pass the companyId to the controller, you can do an ajax call and appending the companyId to the url

Comment: I have a lot of links on this and other pages of the controller. And I need to add them all a parameter